# vscode keeps generating coverage directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what changed recently, but every time I open a folder in vscode, even without running anything (just looking at the files), a **coverage** folder is generated.

What happened? How do I stop that?

Comment: What is a `coverage` folder? Likely, one of your extensions is creating it at launch.

Comment: I was also thinking the same but I keep going over my extensions (not that many) I don’t see anything suspicious...

Comment: Maybe post the list here?

Comment: Will do when I’m back in front of it thanks. Note to the downvoter: it’d be more useful with a feedback...

Comment: So look at what plug ins you installed on your editor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was having the same issue and it seems to be a side effect of Mocha sidebar extension on my machine.  After disabling it, I am no longer getting a coverage directory created.

Comment: or, in that extension, exists an option disable coverage `mocha.coverage: {enable: false}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I had a test config file in my project: jest.config.json (nestjs project), and I had a coverageDirectory variable to indicate where is the coverage folder. I checked that, and I had a different path where the coverage folder didn't exits and this is the reason why my coverage folder was created.

:)